# How to create a new on premises Active Directory from an existing Azure AD tenant populated directly on the cloud?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

Years ago, a customer created and populated an Azure AD tenant directly on the cloud. Now the need to create an on premises Active Directory.

Is there a way to create from scratch a brand new on premises Active Directory which should be and remain synchronized with the already existing Azure AD?

Thank you,
 Stefano

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just got programming questions. You will probably get better responses on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you can build-up on-prem Active directory and sync object to Azure Ad directory with the help of Azure AD connect. More information about sync you can find on this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites)

if stuck somewhere, you can contact Microsoft Support.